# Can't figure why my if statement is not working

Tags: java, if-statement

I can't figure out why my `if` statement is not working. For some reason it always evaluates first `if` statement as `true`, and in result outputs the wrong value.

With `numberOfDays = 19` it should output `4.95`, but instead it outputs `1.65`, because it evaluates first `if` statement as `true` and doesn't change the value of `numberOf7DayPasses`:

```
class TransitCalculator {

    int numberOfRides;
    int numberOfDays;
    double[] prices = { 2.75, 33.00, 127.00 };

    public TransitCalculator(int myRides, int myDays) {
        numberOfRides = myRides;
        numberOfDays = myDays;
    }

    public double unlimited7Price() {
        int numberOf7DayPasses = 1;

        if (numberOfDays % 7 != 0 && numberOfDays / 7 != 1 && numberOfDays / 7 > 1 && numberOfDays / 7 < 2) {
            numberOf7DayPasses = 2;
        } else if (numberOfDays % 7 != 0 && numberOfDays / 7 != 2 && numberOfDays / 7 > 2 && numberOfDays / 7 < 3) {
            numberOf7DayPasses = 3;
        } else if (numberOfDays % 7 != 0 && numberOfDays / 7 != 3 && numberOfDays / 7 > 3 && numberOfDays / 7 < 4) {
            numberOf7DayPasses = 4;
        } else if (numberOfDays % 7 != 0 && numberOfDays / 7 != 4 && numberOfDays / 7 > 4 && numberOfDays / 7 < 5) {
            numberOf7DayPasses = 5;
        } else if (numberOfDays % 7 == 0 && numberOfDays / 7 == 1) {
            numberOf7DayPasses = 1;
        } else if (numberOfDays % 7 == 0 && numberOfDays / 7 == 2) {
            numberOf7DayPasses = 2;
        } else if (numberOfDays % 7 == 0 && numberOfDays / 7 == 3) {
            numberOf7DayPasses = 3;
        } else if (numberOfDays % 7 == 0 && numberOfDays / 7 == 4) {
            numberOf7DayPasses = 4;
        } else if (numberOfDays % 7 == 0 && numberOfDays / 7 == 5) {
            numberOf7DayPasses = 5;
        }
        double priceOfOneRide = numberOf7DayPasses * prices[1] / numberOfRides;

        return priceOfOneRide;
    }
        
        
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TransitCalculator testPerson = new TransitCalculator(20, 19);
        System.out.println(testPerson.unlimited7Price());
    }
}
```

Comment: have you debugged your code? what do you mean "is not working"?

Comment: For the life of me, I can't figure out what kind of logic you're trying ti implement, but I'm pretty sure that it can be done with a lot less code.

Comment: how do you expect an int to be both >1 and <2 ?

Comment: Off topic but our code would be much easier to read if you assigned `numberOfDays % 7` and `numberOfDays / 7` to 2 local variables and then used them in your conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you think it returns 1.65 because the first condition is evaluated true? So I guess you didn't use a debugger to step trough the code to see what really happens!

If the first condition would be evaluated to true, the output would be 3.3 (= 2*33/20)
The output is 1.65 which means none of the conditions evaluates to true.

The first condition (and the 2nd and the 3th and the 4th) can't evaluate to true because they will always be false. The 1st condition contains:

```
numberOfDays / 7 > 1 && numberOfDays / 7 < 2
```

NumberOfDays is an int and because of that the result of numberOfDays / 7 is also an int.
An int can't be greater than 1 and smaller than 2. So the condition will always be false. And in the 2nd, 3th and 4th condition, the numbers are different but they have the same problem.